# Crash when drag iboutlet UICollectionResuseable Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I create a header custom collectionreuseable by Cocoa. I set xib file owner to class but crash when drag iboutlet in to swift file.
"this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key labelXYZ"

Comment: remove the connection from storyboard also. it will be shown as warning. you can see

Comment: only the UICollectionReuseableView met that issue. I don't known why. Maybe a bug? I'm using xCode 10.1